# Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration Chrome

Tags: facebook, google-chrome, url

I've got a send dialog box, which opens when user clicks on a button.
I've got this message when the popup opens: *Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.*

I've also this message in the Chrome console: *Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.*

I've checked my Fb parameters, here they are:

1. Site URL: http://www.mywebsite.com
2. App Domains: mywebsite.com, mywebsite.herokuapp.com, www.mywebsite.com
3. Valid OAuth redirect URIs: http://mywebsite.com, http://mywebsite.herokuapp.com, http://www.mywebsite.com

It does work if I'm browsing using mywebsite.herokuapp.com (but users don't of course), or if I use FF or IE or Safari.
Basically it doesn't work on Chrome with the www.mywebsite.com url.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: So is this a Chrome-_only_ problem, or is it unrelated to the actual browser used to visit your page?

Comment: It is a Chrome-only pb

Comment: Have you tried clearing cache completely and disabling all extensions (if any)? If that doesn’t help – then tell us the real address, so we can have a look at it.

Comment: Yes cache has been cleared and extensions disabled... The website url is www.smeeters.com, you'll need to register using a fb account to test

Comment: Nope, sorry, I’m not gonna register with any site that ask for almost every possible profile info just to test something for someone else.

Comment: So how does your send dialog box work – does it use the JS SDK, do you trigger it by opening a popup with the URL yourself, …?

Comment: The JS SDK is called when the user clicks on the invitation link. This is the content of the function:                                         FB.ui
      method: "send"
      name: "Smeeters"
      link: invitation_url
    , (response) ->
      if response and response.success
        callback(null, true)
      else
        callback(true, null)

Comment: And what does the code embedding the JS SDK look like?

Comment: This is the link where the popup is triggered: _italic_<a href="#" class="invite_friend_link action_button" data-url="http://www.smeeters.com/invitation/472beef0b33c6c50edfbce07?locale=fr&amp;utm_source=facebook&amp;utm_medium=referral&amp;utm_campaign=invite_friend">Invite</a>_italic_ This link has a trigger on click event.